# Unable to delete old workflow process

Tags: web8.5, workflow, bundles

We are using Web 8.5 and we are trying to delete an old **Workflow Process** but the **Bundle** attached to the Process has been removed from the Workflow Instance and deleted. This is now causing the following error when we try to `Force Finish/Revert/Delete` the Process:

> Unable to delete workflow process. The item tcm:xxx-xxx-xxx does not
>   exist

So far, besides trying to `Force Finish/Revert/Delete` the Process, we have tried to finish its *Current Activity* which results in a different error:

> Unable to finish workflow activity for item "tcm:xxx-xxx-xxx" 
>   Unable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VirtualFolder' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Bundle'.

Lastly, we have tried creating a new Bundle in the original location in hopes that the Workflow Process would locate the Bundle by its WebDAV URL, but it seems that it is found by its ID.

Has anyone experienced this issue before, or know how we might go about removing this Workflow Process?

Comment: Sounds like something like SDL support should look at. Please log the support ticket.

Comment: Thanks Anton, it looks like that's what we will have to do.